# Rotina no Server da aplicação Delphi com UNIGUI

Tags: delphi, socket, servidor

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida com componentes UNIGUI para Delphi XE5 e gostaria de saber como posso rodar uma rotina no server da aplicação, sem necessariamente estar na interface do navegador. Uma das rotinas é a comunicação via sockets, essa rotina faz a coleta de dados de uma estação meteriologica e esses dados quero que sejam exibidos na minha interface no navegador, gostaria de saber se é possível coletar essas informações e armazenar em um banco de dados enquanto o server está rodando, sem necessariamente a pagina estar aberta.

Comment: Alex Schmitt, você implementou a sua rotina usando timer? Abraços

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se é uma boa pratica, mas consegui resolver colocando todos os componentes criados dinamicamente dentro do ServerModule, e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Comparei Unigui e Raudus:
Unigui usa ExtJS

[Raudus](http://www.raudus.com) tem uma vcl.js javascript próprio, não depende de terceiro, Mobile e Desktop;
Webservice próprio portado de um versão do fantástico mongoose;
Suporte D7 a XE10 passando por Lázarus;
Todo projeto desenvolvido em Lazarus.